How to resolve "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error
Encountering JavaScript Heap Memory issues during the execution of our TestCafe automation test suite on our Jenkins machine running CentOS 7.7.1908 Linux.
Please find the below error message:

Last few GCs --->
[9201:0x18dd2a0]   244894 ms: Mark-sweep 1958.4 (2081.4) -> 1937.2 (2080.9) MB, 1237.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.344, current mu = 0.344) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[9201:0x18dd2a0]   246494 ms: Mark-sweep 1953.3 (2080.9) -> 1937.8 (2081.1) MB, 1425.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.239, current mu = 0.109) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
1: 0x7f0508e2a268 node::Abort() [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
2: 0x7f0508d17b89  [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
3: 0x7f050a021a00 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
4: 0x7f050a021dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
5: 0x7f050a1e17e5  [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
6: 0x7f050a1e18c5  [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
7: 0x7f050a1f5c5c v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
8: 0x7f050a1f6581 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
9: 0x7f050a1f9749 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
10: 0x7f050a1f97d7 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
11: 0x7f050a1b9fcd v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
12: 0x7f050a55240a v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
13: 0x7f0509f1ccf9  [/lib64/libnode.so.93]
sh: line 1:  9194 Aborted

In our package file, we currently have the following dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "csv-parse": "^5.5.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "downloads-folder": "^3.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.2.0",
    "log4js": "^6.9.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "npm": "^6.14.15",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "save-dev": "^0.0.1-security",
    "testcafe": "^3.6.2",
    "testcafe-reporter-custom": "^1.2.1",
    "testcafe-reporter-html": "^1.4.6",
    "testcafe-reporter-junit": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mkdirp": "^3.0.1"
  }

Node version: 'v16.18.1'
I've tried few methods in my package.json file
node --max_old_space_size=1024 npm testcafe chrome \<my file\>

Also using process.memoryUsage() I grabbed the heap total and heap used values
{
rss: 975765504,
heapTotal: 883564544,
heapUsed: 838497000,
external: 2417679,
arrayBuffers: 156348
}


Hi, please read formatting help
